# How can animate a sequence of pictures in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, flash

Can anybody explain how to use flash in asp.net mvc3 to animate a sequence of pictures or suggest a good tutorial. I didn't find a good one to start. It's first time I want to use flash. Any answers can be helpful. Thanks